# cant place marker in google map inside of geojson

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I dont have experience with google maps. Im loading a geojson in a map, and I have a listener on the click event to place a marker. The problem is it works when i click outside the region, but not inside.

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
 var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
 var mapOptions = {
    center: {lat: 41.8708, lng: -87.6505},    
    zoom: 14
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
  });
  // map.data.loadGeoJson('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cgansen/6458644/raw/5a9ec31defab0073853831b7fc7de0f87eb66a2d/wards-from-city-unsimplified.geojson');
   map.data.loadGeoJson('https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/geospatial/cauq-8yn6?method=export&format=GeoJSON');

   var myLatLng = {lat: 41.8708, lng: -87.6505};
   //Illinois University Marker
   var image = 'js/i1.png';
   var Umarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Department of Computer Science – University of Illinois!',
    icon: image
  });


   
}

function placeMarker(map, location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I changed your code around a little - but the secret sauce you're looking for is the following:

```
// Add the click event to the new polygon layer as well as the map itself.
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(map, event.latLng)
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cguju62a/

Good luck!